# What is the way to write a manifold of manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, grassmannian

I want to write this in mathematical notation: "Let us represent a ball, $B_3$, with a metric $g$ as a point on manifold. Let $M$ be the (infinite dimensional) manifold formed from every ball with all possible smooth metrics." In such a way that smoothly going from one point on $M$ to another smoothly varies the metric of the ball.

Does this "manifold of manifolds" have a name? (This would be a topological manifold unless one defined some kind of `meta metric' on it.)

**Edit**: As Michael pointed out this is more precisely described as 'a space such that every point corresponds to a Riemannian metric on $B_3$.'

Comment: This is basically the definition of Riemanian manifold if I understand your definition correctly. Note that, in a manifold, the metric is not defined on the manifold itself, but rather on the tangent space of each point on that manifold.

Comment: "Every ball with all possible smooth metrics" is a bit of a vague concept. Once you define this clearly, how does this set form an infinite dimensional manifold? When are two balls close to each other?

Comment: It seems like you are describing a space such that every point corresponds to a Riemannian metric on $B^3$. Is that right?

Comment: @Michael yes. that's right. `Space' or 'manifold' seem somewhat interchangeable to me. e.g is $\mathbb{R}^3$ a space or an infinite flat manifold? I guess a manifold is an unlabelled space? e.g. the space of all 2D rotations is a circle $S_1$.

Comment: @zooby: A space usually refers to a topological space, while a manifold is a very specific type of topological space; the two terms are not interchangeable. Every manifold is a (topological) space, but not conversely.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general comments.

If $M$ is a smooth manifold, the collection of Riemannian metrics on $M$ is an open subset of the infinite-dimensional vector space $\Gamma(M, S^2(TM)^*)$ where $S^2$ denotes the second symmetric power.

If $M$ is compact, $\Gamma(M, S^2(TM)^*)$ is a Fréchet space, and hence the collection of Riemannian metrics on $M$ is an infinite-dimensional Fréchet manifold.

Comment: If we take all metrics on $B_3$ that all share a common metric on the boundary $S_3$, then I wonder would this a be closed Frechet Manifold?